# android how to put communique from web to app

Tags: android, web, textview

I'm trying to find out, how can i put into my app short communique
from web. It would be short String about new updates etc. I want to put this String to web and then when user starts my app, it automatically put this short String sequence into TextView. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use http://jsoup.org/ to web scrape your communique.  From there it is easy to apply the message to a text View.